# Install McAfee And Nod32

Tags: networking, windows-xp, anti-virus, nod32

I have a computer with Windows XP Service Pack 3 as an operating system. This computer is in a network with a McAfee update server. This server will install and update the McAfee client on all computers in that network. When I install and running 'Eset Nod32 Smart Security (AntiVirus)', the computer hangs. It does not works in Safe Mode. How can I install both Nod32 and McAfee on this network?

**After Edit**

I only want to install Node32 Antivirus.

Comment: Why do you wanna use both Nod32 and McAfee ?

Comment: I wouldn't install two different antiviruses (antivirusii?). They will clash with each other, not to mention the slowdown from their normal operation...

Comment: Two antiviruses = REALLY SLOW SYSTEM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in a managed environment where McAfee is forced onto your computer, chances are you shouldn't be trying to install a different AV and the computer probably isn't yours. I'd contact your Systems Administrator with any concerns that you might have, but they have probably gone to great lengths to make sure that you cannot do this.